# XML file with UTF-8 encoding contains hex 2026, which messes up xerces

Tags: xml, unicode, utf-8, ellipsis

I have an app that uses the Xerces XML parser, and which messes up with a file that  presumably intended to have an ellipsis (3 dots) character in a text field.

The file says it's in utf-8 encoding:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And the string in question looks like this in Notepad:

```
   <tvo:BuylineDescription>LOCAL NEWS …NOT AIRING 9/3</tvo:BuylineDescription>
```

i.e., Chrome and Notepad both see an ellipsis character in there.  But if I do a hex dump of the file, what's really there is hex 2026, which the hex dump app interprets as a space and an ampersand.

```
4C4F43414C204E45 575320264E4F5420 LOCAL NEWS &NOT
414952494E472039 2F333C2F74766F3A AIRING 9/3</tvo:
```

Hex 2026 is the unicode value for an ellipsis, but this isn't a unicode file.  Okay, so maybe the app that produced the file just copied in unicode that was copy/pasted from somewhere (yes, I think the user intended for an ellipsis to be there).  But why are these apps interpreting this 2-byte sequence as unicode within a UTF-8 XML file?  And if those apps see an ellipsis, why does it mess up Xerces?  I.e., is this legal UTF-8 or not?  Oh, and this file was received as a single SOAP 'string' variable - so maybe some code translation happened in transit...

Bottom line is - my app can't handle this file. but if I replace the ampersand with three periods, Xerces has no problem with it.  So either I need to prescan for this character sequence and replace it, or get the sender to stop sending it.  But of course there are cases where a space followed by an ampersand is legal, so prescanning could get tricky.

Is this an age old problem that others have long since figured out how to deal with?  I see a lot of similar posts here - just nothing that seems to quite match.

Answer (score 1):

There's certainly something strange going on here. If the file really contains the two bytes x20 x26 as your hex dump shows, then I can't see how any application would interpret that as an ellipsis rather than as (space, ampersand).

It is perfectly legal UTF-8. Interpreted as UTF-8, it is (space, ampersand) and Xerces is choking not because it's bad UTF-8, but because there's an ampersand that doesn't introduce a legal entity or character reference.

The UTF-8 encoding of ellipsis is three bytes, xE2 x80 xA6.

I'm always suspicious of hex dumps. Some tools show you what's in memory, not what's on disk, and it's not always the same. If I'm feeling paranoid, I use my own code to read the file as a byte stream and print each byte in hex (there's code in Saxon to do this: `java net.sf.saxon.functions.UnparsedText input.xml`)

Comment: Umm.  This hex dump was produced by a program I wrote that does read the file as a byte stream and print each byte in hex...  But 'od' and other utilities show the same sequence.  But in any case, I suspect you're right about Xerces thinking this ampersand is the start of a special character sequence, but getting flummoxed by what follows.  So, given that - and the fact that I can't get the sender to fix it, or Xerces to handle it, how would you suggest I pre-scan these XML files to replace *just these* ampersands with something innocuous - without breaking true ampersand-flagged characters?

Comment: For what it's worth, our sysadmin already processes these files through a script that uses sed to replace other nasty characters that shouldn't be there.  But this ampersand is a perfectly valid character - except for the fact that it's in the wrong place...

Comment: So you're already patching up a file that's known to be badly encoded, and your patches aren't fixing the whole problem? I'm afraid that's typical of duct-tape solutions to encoding problems. You need to find out where the bad data got into the system and fix it at source.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the original XML file contained a valid xE2 x80 xA6 UTF-8 ellipsis, but a store-and-forward box that sits between me and the file creator was corrupting it.  Don't know exactly how, but I know that the store-and-forward box stores the XML text temporarily in a SQL Server database.  So, my guess is that it stores it in a text field that can't handle UTF-8, and that's where the corruption happens.

For what it's worth, Xerces handles the good UTF-8 ellipsis okay, but either it (or my application) truncates the string at the ellipsis.  I'll leave that for another day.  Just glad to know gSoap doesn't corrupt UTF-8 text in transit.